Amplitude of FFT in python
I have the following code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq

def polarization(t):
    f = x*np.cos(2*np.pi*omega*t)/np.sqrt(1+(x*np.cos(2*np.pi*omega*t))**2)
    return f

omega = 100
x = 5

N = 10000
t_max = 1
t = np.linspace(0,t_max,N)

yf = fft(polarization(t))
yf = 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2])

np.max(yf)

which outputs 1.21. I am not sure I understand this value, as the maximum value obtained by my function is 1, so any frequency component should have a value below that.
How can I convert this 1.21 value to the actual amplitude of the associated frequency component?

"so any frequency component should have a value below that" -- famously the coefficient of the fundamental frequency of a square wave (swinging between 1 and -1) is 4/pi which is about 1.27

Thank you for this, but why would I divide by that in this case?
